# JSON not working on iOS app Unity 5

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm working on iOS app on Unity and I get problem.
For data storage I use JSON, and in Unity I use Newtonsoft.Json (I download dll files from official site and add to Unity project version for .Net 2.0).

When I start scene in Unity on Mac all works fine, but when I build project for iPhone and start scene on iPhone XCode output this log (and elements do not add to Dropdown).

In scene from json file I get List of my elements and add to Dropdown.

```
public Dropdown anions;
public Dropdown cations;

StreamReader reader;
string json;
SolubilityTable solubility;

public void Start() { //When I start Scene
    reader = new StreamReader (Application.dataPath + "/Data/solubilityTable.json");
    json = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    solubility = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SolubilityTable>(json);

    anions.AddOptions (solubility.anions);
    cations.AddOptions (solubility.cations);
}
```

Log:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not     found...ctor() of System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter'.
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean     nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in     <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter (System.Type     type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetTypeConverter     (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.GetConverter (System.Type     t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CanConvertToString     (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Solubility.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

Comment: What does the Json you receive look like? Can you paste the Json file received here?

Comment: @Programmer https://github.com/diniska/chemistry/blob/master/PeriodicalTable/periodicTable.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Unity's Jason API JsonUtility.FromJson.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Element
{
    public string group;
    public int position;
    public string name;
    public object number;
    public string small;
    public double molar;
    public int[] electrons;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Table
{
    public string wiki;
    public Element[] elements;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Lanthanoid
{
    public string group;
    public int position;
    public string name;
    public int number;
    public string small;
    public double molar;
    public int[] electrons;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Actinoid
{
    public string group;
    public int position;
    public string name;
    public int number;
    public string small;
    public double molar;
    public int[] electrons;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class SolubilityTable
{
    public Table[] table;
    public Lanthanoid[] lanthanoids;
    public Actinoid[] actinoids;
}

System.IO.StreamReader reader;
string json;
SolubilityTable solubility;

void Start()
{
    solubility = new SolubilityTable();
    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Data/solubilityTable.json");
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    solubility = JsonUtility.FromJson<SolubilityTable>(json);


    //Show all wiki from Table
    for (int i = 0; i < solubility.table.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Got: " + solubility.table[i].wiki);
    }
}
```

**Helpful Note**:

Also consider using this [site](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate class from Json when you have problems like this. When you are done, simply change all the `Lists` to `arrays` and remove auto property `{ get; set; }` from all of the variables. Unity's built Json Serializer will then work. Tested with **5.40.B13** and I recommend you update to this version if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's work fine. I don't change List to array.

Comment: @IvanIstomin You are welcome.  When I said change List to Array, I  meant you should do so when you use the website I put in the answer to generate class for your Json. For now you don't have to because I have already done that for you.